# how to interpret session waite reason in ingres ipm?

Tags: performance, session, deadlock, monitor, ingres

I am using **ipm** for monitoring an ingres database (Ingres 10 on RedHat).

In the **Wait Reason** of the session I notice : **DIOR, DIOW, LIOR, LIOW, BIOR, BIOW, Log, Lock, LGEvnt, LKEvnt**.

I have searched the documentation and googled the net but I can't find a detailed interpretation.

**Edit :**
My question is : what means each of those Waiting Reasons ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question! In other words, please add a sentence that ends with a "?" (question mark) to your question. Thanks!

Comment: any one has answer, please .... !!